# How to Repeat Bootstrap Containers in Jade?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I have JSON data being sent from Express and Mongoose Stack to be rendered for the UI programmed in Jade. 
What Jade Construct should I use to repeat a Bootstrap Container of col-md-4 using the Jade syntax.

Currently my Jade Code is as follows,

```
 if deal
each item in deal
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4
    .thumbnail
      img(alt='100%x200', src='#{item.image_url}', style='height: 250px; width: 100%;')
      .caption

        h3 
          | #{item.brand_id}
```

But I get an error,

```
Cannot read property 'image_url' of undefined
```

My JSON data is sent like this,

```
Deal.find(function(err, result){
    if(err) return console.log("Error" + err);
    res.render('home',{deal:result});
```

});

What can be a possible solution to repeat Blocks of data from the content served in JSON format?

Comment: Have you tried to actually define `item`?

Comment: No. deal is a JSON Array Object, and for each iteration of this Array Object I want to repeat the above Block.

Comment: if deal is indeed an array of objects, your code should work fine.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli  I've edited to show the serverside way of sending data.      Let me try once. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems correct, make sure that 'deal' is indeed populated with the correct data. 
here's a working example:

```
- var list = [{x: 123, y: 234}, {x: 123, y: 234}];
each item in list
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4
    .thumbnail
      img(alt='100%x200', src='#{item.x}', style='height: 250px; width: 100%;')
      .caption

        h3
          | #{item.y}
```

output:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img alt="100%x200" src="123" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"/>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>234</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img alt="100%x200" src="123" style="height: 250px; width: 100%;"/>
    <div class="caption">
      <h3>234</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```